# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'value' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Im getting this Error:

```
(3/3) QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'value' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `users` where exists (select * from `permission_templates` inner join `permissions` on `permission_templates`.`value` = `permissions`.`value` where `users`.`id` = `permissions`.`user_id` and (`value` = TICKET_LIST or `value` = MASTER) and `permission_templates`.`deleted_at` is null) and `id` != 3 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

If I run this

```
        $collaborators = User::whereHas('permissions', function($query) {
            $query->where('value', 'TICKET_LIST')
                ->orWhere('value', 'MASTER');
        })->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())
            ->get();
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: I rolled back back your edit because it invalidates the answer. If you have a new question then you need to ask in a new post.

Answer (score 5):

look like you have a column with name 'value' in your users table.

to resolve this, you just have to add table name before column name  in where,

```
  $collaborators = User::whereHas('permissions', function($query) {
            $query->where('permissions.value', 'TICKET_LIST')
                ->orWhere('permissions.value', 'MASTER');
        })->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())
            ->get();
```